# Printing out 25 most recently added tables

Tags: php, mysql

In the code below, I allow users to add tables to a MySQL database.  Is there a way to print out the most recent 25 tables added?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$table = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$query = "CREATE TABLE `$table` (id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, site VARCHAR(350) NOT NULL, cat1 BIGINT(9) NOT NULL, cat2 BIGINT(9) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id), UNIQUE (site))";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select TABLE_NAME
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 where TABLE_SCHEMA='your_db_name`
 order by CREATE_TIME desc
 limit 25
```

This is for MySQL version 5 and above. It will list tables created by your users *and* you, though.

Comment: This seems like it should work in theory, but it reports incorrect values for me in practice. It seems like it describes when a row was last inserted or something like that rather than when it was created. This is strange because it should contain the creation time of the table according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Comment: It works correctly for me for MyISAM / InnoDB tables. Doesn't work for "Memory" (create_time is null), which I suppose makes sense.

Comment: thanks... how would i print this query out as a one-column, 25-row table?

Comment: You mean via PHP?
`$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
 echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_free_result($result);`

Answer (score 1):

You can but I'd advise creating a history or audit table of all the table creations (and other relevant activity). For example:

```
$now = time();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$sql = <<<END
INSERT INTO table_history
(table, user, action, action_time)
VALUES
('$table', '$user', 'CREATE', $now)
END;
mysql_query($sql) or die($sql . ': ' . mysql_error());
```

Also, I'd probably suggest not creating a separate table for each instance you need to use it unless they're going to be really large. Creating another column to identify the user, organization or whatever is often (but not always) a better approach.